# Is there any version of triangulation of orbifolds

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology, differential-topology, triangulation, orbifolds

Every closed manifold admits a triangulation, but is it true for closed orbifold? The simplex in the triangulation should be replaced by some orbifold versions, otherwise it must be a manifold. Thanks a lot!

Comment: You meant to say that every **smooth** closed manifold admits a triangulation. (This is false for topological manifolds.) Did you try to repeat the manifold proof in the orbifold setting? If so, where did you get stuck? http://www.math.harvard.edu/~lurie/937notes/937Lecture4.pdf